# Web cam showing low resolution video when using flash cs3

Tags: camera, webcam, resolution, flash-cs3

In my web app i am using flash to get the live streaming of my web cam ,and then to display that to my web page using the swf file generated after publishing the Flash file.But the problem i am facing is that the video is not shown in good resolution.I tried many settings but nothing worked.Here is my code for getting the video in Flash.

```
var camera;
var video;
var bandwidth:int = 100;
var quality:int = 100;

camera=Camera.getCamera();
camera.setMode(190,130,10000);
camera.setQuality(bandwidth*1024/8, quality);
video = new Video(camera.width * 2.5, camera.height *2.4);
video.attachCamera(camera);
video.smoothing;
addChild(video);
```

Can anyone please tell me ,what i am doing wrong here.Any solutions to get the video with high resolution.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed.i was doing a minor mistake of providing greater height and width of video than that of camera height and video.Just removed that stuff and my video resolution was back on track.The change in code is :

Changed the line of code

```
video = new Video(camera.width * 2.5, camera.height *2.4);
```

to

```
video = new Video(camera.width, camera.height);
```